# Understanding STS: Spring boot application works fine from STS but when gradle is used to build jar, the build fails

Tags: eclipse, spring-boot, gradle, spring-tool-suite

My spring boot application works fine when run from Spring Tool Suite. However at the time of project deployment when I use Gradle command to build jar file, I get compile error - with error message saying a specific package is missing.
The root cause was that I had missed to add a specific dependency to build.gradle. After adding the missing dependency the build was successful.

Can someone explain how STS was able to refer to the "missing" dependency and able to run the application successfully in development environment?
Is it that STS and Gradle has two different locations where dependencies are stored?

Comment: Without knowing what you did in STS this is impossible to answer. Did you only import the build? Did you manually add jars/modules to the list of dependencies used in STS instead of adding them to the build (sure looks like that).

Comment: I did not manually add jars in STS for sure. I will recall what settings I did in STS and post the details

Comment: My initial guess is - I copied code snippet (related to the new dependency) from another STS to the current above project in question. So internally STS might have got info of the new dependency hence it works in STS. I will confirm it and add details

Comment: If the dependency was added manually instead of using the gradle build to include the dependency it will work in STS but not the gradle build. As only STS knows about it not Gradle.

Comment: @M.Deinum so does this mean that STS will maintain a separate location where all dependent classes exists and Gradle maintains a separate repository.

Comment: Not if you use gradle to manage your dependencies. Only if you manually (or through some helper) add jars to the classpath of your project.

Comment: @M.Deinum your response ...
"If the dependency was added manually instead of using the gradle build to include the dependency it will work in STS but not the gradle build. As only STS knows about it not Gradle" makes sense. Can you add this as the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using STS (or any other IDE for that matter) and you are manually (or through a wizard) adding jars to the classpath entries those will only be available in your IDE.

What you should be doing is adding additional dependencies to your `pom.xml` or  `build.gradle` (depending on your tooling), which then in turn should be picked up by your IDE again.

**NOTE:** Some IDEs will automatically detect additions to the classpath and add them to your build files as well. Not sure if STS (and thus Eclipse) does this.